# Can't access function after chown command

Tags: server, chown

I was using this command `chown root:www-data /var/www/example.com -R`,
but there was a message shown that directory not listed.

Comment: And why did you change it to "root"?

Answer (score 0):

Once you chown it to owner root and group www-data, in order to access that folder you either have to be the root user, or in the www-data group.

You can add yourself to the www-data group by doing this.

`usermod -a -G www-data [your username]`

Or you can use sudo to perform any tasks as root.

`sudo ls -l /var/www/example.com`

Or, if you of course not let root own it at all, which there shouldn't be a reason to.

`chown [your username]:www-data /var/www/example.com`

Answer (score 0):

The right sintax:

```
sudo chown -R root:www-data /var/www/example.com
```

Parameter `-R` have to be first.